# Appropriate way to deal with missing value in both training and test data

Tags: neural-networks, python, missing-data, mice

In the medical data, it's normal that there are lots of missing value.
Now I am dealing with the data with tens of numerical features and many of them have lots of missing value for sure.

The dataset has only 188453 data(time stamp) with label 0 or 1, which is not a very big dataset so I'm not really intent to deleting data, and most of the label are 0(90% of the dataset). 
Quantity of some features are even below 10% of the whole dataset.
Missing ratio in two labels are almost the same(correlation coefficient are almost 1).

I know there are several ways to deal with missing value, like deleting, mean imputation, and so on.
I may try to use MICE though I don't know if it would work cause I notice that correlation coefficient in some features are not the same between label 0 and 1.
For example, in label 0, corr coef between feature A and B is low, but high in label 1.

So, my question is:

1. For those features which amount are below 10%(some even below 1 %), should I just give up them or it is okay to try to do MICE?
2. I think it's better to do MICE differently for label 0 and label 1 cause corr coef in some features are not the same, but if I do so, I may not know how to deal with missing value in test data cause I wouldn't know the label of test data.
3. Quantity of two labels are very imbalance. I don't have idea of how to do data augmentation with so much missing values.

Or if there are better ways to dealing situation like this, I am welcome to know. Sincerely thanks for reading my question and looking forward for answers!

Comment: Normally I would say do whatever works, but you mentioned you're working with medical data.  What is the goal of the analysis?

Comment: To predict the label is 0 or 1 with given test data. And I would do training with ANN or RNN.

Comment: I mean what are you going to do with those predictions?  Will you be applying this to a clinical setting, or is this just for fun?

Comment: It's a competition. But for me, it's more like a practice of dealing with data and doing ML/DL things. So I want to make every of my step reasonable to learn these skill.

Comment: OK.  For those variables with lots of missing data, you could try recoding them to be categorical.  If they are binary, they become a 3 category variable.  If they are continuous, bin the data in a way you think is reasonable (cross validate your approach).  Try MICE for the remainder.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I would try it, thank you! :)